# Get all values of a managed property

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

How can I fetch all the values of a managed property using SharePoint REST API search query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get all the possible Refiners for your Managed Property, you can use the following:

`https://mysite/_api/search/query?QueryText='*'&selectproperties='Department'&Refiners='Department'&RowLimit=0`

where `Department` being the managed property..

Reference:

[Querying SharePoint 2013 Search Index for Managed Property Values / Refiners using REST API](http://techblurt.com/2014/05/28/querying-sharepoint-2013-search-index-for-managed-property-values-refiners-using-rest-api/)

Comment: This will only pull back the top 100 refiner results: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/118635/what-is-the-maximum-records-will-be-returned-for-refiners-search-in-sharepoint-s

Answer (score 0):

I think the only reliable way to do this is to somehow convert the column into managed metadata and use the term store api to fetch all of the terms for the term set.