# What is the maximum records will be returned for refiners search in sharepoint search API?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin

I am making a call for a refiner search which is just randomly return 100 records back? How can i increase this return count of records?

I have set my page size as 1 in my search criteria. Is this is the problem?

my request is going like this `http://myapp:portnumber/_api/search/postquery,startindex=0,rowlimit=1`

Comment: Which search api you are using? Using REST we can change the TotalRows property

Comment: my request is going like this {http://myapp:portnumber/_api/search/postquery,startindex=0,rowlimit=1} and i am getting returned of 100 records.

Comment: do you have more than 100 results?

Comment: Yes. I am sure , i have more than 100 records in my sharepoint. But i am getting 100 records from the sharepoint for the above query.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to get more that 100 refiners. Just add filter parameter to your refiner.

below query returns more that 100 refiners (but less than 1000). Here 1000 is the limit of refiner.

eg. - `https://SiteURL/_api/search/query?querytext='You_Query_TEXT'&refiners='REFINER_NAME(filter=1000/0/*)'&trimduplicates=false&rowlimit=1`

Answer (score -1):

You can increase the total number using RowLimit property

```
myapp:portnumber/_api/search/postquery,startindex=0,rowlimit=500
```

If the install is On-Premise then you can increase the 500 limit using PowerShell

Another option is to iterate 500 initial result and then re-query the next 500 and so on. For that you can use

```
myapp:portnumber/_api/search/postquery,rowlimit=500&startrow=500
```

Comment: my query is how i am getting 100 records when i am passing rowlimit as 1 and startindex as 0. I am still not clear about this point?

Comment: I am not sure about the value 1. Can you try removing the startindex and put rowlimit=30?

Comment: In my understanding the question is not about the number of search results returned but the number of refinement values which is independent from the row limit.